# Is there a better way to validate associated record in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails3 and I have following code

```
class Utensil < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :manufacturer_id
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

Is that the right way to validate a belongs_to object. I have a feeling that validating id might not be the best strategy. Any alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is just fine.  If you want to validate the associated model as well, you can fo the following:

```
class Utensil < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer

  validates_associated :manufacturer
  validates_presence_of :manufacturer_id
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: these methods are deprecated in ror 3, are not they?

Comment: @GearHead - not that I'm aware of.  There is no mention of deprecation in either the API Docs or Rails Guides.

Comment: sorry, you are right. these methods will be deprecated in 3.1 and deleted in 3.2 :)

Comment: They were not deprecated, just moved.